# Not getting amazon SalesRank using amazon API

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I was using ItemLookup to get SalesRank using Amazon Product API. I am using [python amazon product api](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/)

```
import amazonproduct
from lxml import objectify 
config = {
    'access_key': 'access key',
    'secret_key': 'secret key',
    'associate_tag': 'associate tag',
    'locale': 'us'
}
amazon = amazonproduct.API(cfg=config) 

result = amazon.item_lookup('B01B83IWH0', ResponseGroup="SalesRank")
```

but when i print the results their is no SalesRank, has amazon stopped giving SalesRank?

```
AttributeError: no such child: {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}SalesRank
```

I tried using amazon scratchpad but it also didn't give SalesRank but they have mention in their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_SalesRank.html) to get SalesRank. How do I get SalesRank or if their is any alternative(I tried web scraping but amazon blocks me frequently). Please help, I am a beginner in using API's.

Answer (score 0):

Using this library:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-simple-product-api

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

api = AmazonAPI(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_KEY_SECRET, amazon_tag)

item= api.item_lookup('B01B83IWH0')

# Get Sales Rank
rank = item.sales_rank
```

This gets rank, but doesn't seem to reflect the current rank listed on Amazon's website. I'm only just familiarizing myself with the Amazon API, will update with elaboration and details.